# List Definition and List Instance: which should be used when?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on VS 2010 for creating List Instances and List Definitions of SharePoint but I am not getting to know which one is to be used when? And basically what differentiates the two?

Answer (score 1):

**List Definition:**

A list definition defines a schema for a SharePoint list. It contains information on what views are being used, which columns and content types are being used, and other metadata information.

**List Instance:**

A list instance is an instance of a specific SharePoint list definition. All of its data is stored in the relevant content database. Typically a list in SharePoint used by end users to enter and view data and it is based on either a list definition.